# TeamViewer: how to allow one time connection?

Tags: teamviewer

I have teamviewer installed on a remote computer, protected by a long complicated password.  I'd like someone to join a session so that they can see what I'm doing on the remote, but I don't want to give the the password. One reason I don't want to give the permanent password is that they usually have problems correctly entering long passwords.

I suppose I could temporarily change the access password, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

I don't have physical access to the remote computer. It's a windows machine running teamviewer 9, I connect with a laptop and the other person would be using the ipad app.

What can I do to give them access for the one session?

Comment: You have two options: 1) help the person type in the password or 2) change the password. I think you've answered your own question, right?

Comment: @EEAA See Esa Jokinen's answer. I'm not in the same location as the other person, making it difficult to help them type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamViewer has by default a random password that changes on every reboot and can be manually changed by pressing an arrow button alongside. The *personal password* provided in setup is different type of authentication and does not change in this operation.

For one time access I suggest either

- providing the random password from *allow remote control* section in main window and changing it after the connection
- providing only the ID and accepting the incoming connection

Comment: I don't currently have access to the remote, so will test once I do an revert. I didn't realize that you can have both a personal password (what I called a permanent password) and a random password.

Comment: The random password worked.  However, when using an app to connect, the app asked for a password and nothing appeared on the remote about accepting an incoming connection.